# How to set acceptable number values for .equals(); command?

Tags: java

I have here a problem regarding my program. I want to accept a range of values regarding on my edittext.

What I want to happen is to accept values ranging from 1-50. But i dont know how will i do it. I've set int, but it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Here is my simple code:

```
REDIRECT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Amount = txtbox1.getText().toString();

                if(Amount.equals(Here is the range of values that i want to accept from 1-50 numbers only))
                {

                final Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Redirect.class);               
                startActivity(i);
                }
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `equals` for this:

```
try{
    int a=Integer.parseInt(txtbox1.getText().toString());
    if(i<=50&&i>=1){
        //it's in the range. Handle it
    }
}catch(NumberFormatExcepion e){
    //handle invalid input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.equals()` will only check for equality against one `String` argument. You can't change that. If you want to match on one of many Strings, perhaps write a loop over `.equals()` like so:

```
private boolean matchesOneOf(String string, String[] strings) {
    for(String thisString : strings) {
        if(string.equals(thisString)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or better yet use an existing library class method such as List.contains()

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("1");
strings.add("2");
strings.add("3");
...
strings.add("50");

if(strings.contains(txtbox1.getText().toString())){ 
    // do stuff if value is in the list of strings you specified
}
```

Anyway from the looks of this example you don't want a `String` but a numeric type (probably `int`) for `amount`. Then range checking becomes vastly simpler with the `< > <= >=` operators for example.